# C3 js Tooltip X axis issue while moving the cursor

Tags: tooltip, c3.js

I am using c3.js to render a graph. My tooltip is only moving along y axis and not on x axis.

Comment: You will need to supply more details if you hope to get a answer.

Comment: It is designed like that to show all series data, If you have more data points on x-axis tooltip is shown for all of them.